# How to fix "volume group <old-vg-name> not found" at boot after renaming it?

Tags: linux, boot, lvm

I renamed my rootfs vg and changed the name in `/etc/fstab` and `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` so I can enter the system as before. However, in every boot, the screen is occupied by

```
Volume group "<old-vg-name>" not found
Cannot process volume group <old-vg-name>
```

which is annoying.

Is it possible to stop the system printing such message?

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to Stalin Vignesh Kumar's link. Here is my solution on debian.

After running `vgrename` and change the name in `/etc/fstab` and `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, and reboot for the first time (or several times), I checked `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` for swap path and ran `dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-4.19.0-8-amd64`. This regenerates the initramfs and grub. The problem disappears in next rebooting.

I guess a reconfiguration of image package may be unnecessary, as it calls `update-initramfs` to regenerate the initramfs. Running `update-initramfs -u` should also work, and do not need to specify the version of kernel.

Comment: [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/650774/debian-volume-group-debian-vg-not-found-on-every-boot)'s also how to squash the messages, if like me, `update-initramfs -u` didn't do it for you. :P

Answer (score 2):

You need to activate vg and refresh it volumes i guess.

Try this

https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-how-to-rename-the-volume-group-for-root-and-swap/

Comment: Thanks! I used `dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-4.19.0-8-amd64` and the problem is solved. I guess `update-initramfs -u` should also work.

Comment: Cool!!! Thanks for the update.