# Debian - Volume group "debian-vg" not found on every boot

Tags: linux, debian, lvm, luks

On every boot of my debian system, the following warnings appear:
Volume group "debian-vg" not found.
Skipping volume group "debian-vg"
Volume group "debian-vg" not found.
Skipping volume group "debian-vg"
After which it asks for the disk password, and everything is fine.
How do I get rid of these warnings? Reinstalling does nothing, even on multiple machines.

System info:
Debian 5.10.28-1, Linux aloha 5.10.0-6-amd64

Answer (score 3):

This is a long-standing Debian bug (albeit a cosmetic one). Check out this bug report: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=544651

If it bothers you, patch it like so:

```
--- /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/lvm2 2017-03-17 19:03:07.000000000 +0300
+++ /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/lvm2 2019-08-17 17:40:29.371725145 +0300
@@ -20,7 +20,15 @@
 fi
.
 lvchange_activate() {
-    lvm lvchange -aay -y --sysinit --ignoreskippedcluster "$@"
+    # Workaround for making LVM less noisy.
+    # See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linux.debian.bugs.dist/iAAVTXslawQ ("Bug#799295: lvm2: Errors about lvmetad on boot")
+    if grep -sqw "quiet" /proc/cmdline; then
+        mkdir -p /run/log
+        echo "Running script '$0' on $(date)" >> /run/log/initrd-lvm.log 2>&1
+        lvm lvchange -aay -y --sysinit --ignoreskippedcluster "$@" >> /run/log/initrd-lvm.log 2>&1
+    else
+        lvm lvchange -aay -y --sysinit --ignoreskippedcluster "$@"
+    fi
 }
.
 activate() {
```

Basically, copy /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/lvm2 to /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/lvm2, patch it (e.g. using the patch above or something similar), then add the `quiet` parameter to your kernel command line.

Rebuild your initramfs.

Reboot.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Any idea as to why they are not fixing this? I'm genuinely curious. Also you deserve more cookies, these annoying messages are finally gone!

Comment: I think Debian *is* moving towards a nicer, quieter boot experience, but it's not a super-high priority for them. The user base is more hardcore and not as easily upset by spurious boot messages as the Ubuntu folks, for example :) Just a guess.

Anyway, glad I could help :)